# Self-referencing a mapped type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm modeling an AST for a small language in Typescript. I'm trying to transform this type:

```js
type Lang<T> = {
  Literal: { value: string | number | boolean },
  BinOp: { op: string, lhs: T, rhs: T },
  UnOp: { op: string, arg: T },
  // ...more fields
};
```

Into this:

```js
type ASTNode =
  { type: 'Literal', value: string | number | boolean } |
  { type: 'BinOp', op: string, lhs: ASTNode, rhs: ASTNode } |
  { type: 'UnOp', op: string, arg: ASTNode }
  // ... more types
;
```

I think the solution is something along these lines:

```js
type ASTNodeAux<T> = {
    [K in keyof Lang<T>]: { type: K } & Lang<T>[K]
};
type ASTNode = ASTNodeAux<ASTNode>[keyof ASTNodeAux<ASTNode>];
```

But this isn't accepted by TypeScript since `ASTNode` references itself. From what I saw the workaround is usually to use interfaces instead, but I don't see how I can do this together with mapped types. Is there any way to achieve this?

*For extra context, I am trying to avoid the need to write type types multiple times while providing accurate type signatures for AST nodes and the arguments of `fold`, `forEach` and other combinators ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=43&ssc=27&pln=43&pc=13#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYB4AqA+KBeKBvAWACgpYBLYCAJzgBsAufKANzoFcJGBnYKs5KAB8oCNgFsARtSFQJAezm0IiKAF8ANMVIAhfgHkwjPFDmGoPPsnVRaACy6M01qvcdrNJKAFUEBoybMLfiRrOCokNw0tKAB6GKgAOiTiVQBuYgyiOKgAWjz8gsKi4pKSzOyASSgIAA9IAGNKABMoYFtoADNFWjkAd2DWuVloCABHNjJWJQRgQfpibNBIKABBAGU0ADk5JuhsBfjSYyXOKAByGApqOjPrKY5uXgHhUUlpYXlFZQQ1IQPSJgnRhnXS+MC3AKPSwhGyuVYbba7Zxw9ZbHbQVR-LKHQHgU5nHwGCGmKHBULhRioxEY-6kbJJBL-dJEE7wtG7FZsGroLC4QieUgAbQA0lB+FAANYQEByDqwRCoTAAXX8QKgosxADJ5cgeSKlSlmayqeicGzqZzuSbdhhBVKZXLrRBLSgnRglcziB02AhGmQ5D8uHIxBAAGI++oACgQ6MpCPRAEpGMw5GQWvyAa1bFQ+iIIL0oABRKg5qiRs4x2ZkMRgJQhmYQJpnBPM1TleL1OQliCNYhBkPh32R4544GXSg0WgQ+6nABEcAk9Vnahb7agne7vaI-bDEeH0VIaoJYNuB8h5xyp4FUDCEVxkDHV0n0-YpwALAAmNQpVdEf78DcqB7YA+2DXch2MSsAH04CgmNdkYURaFoFdPWxMVfS7ICtx3QcoxHB9zgqBApjTak0DxM5ULXACsOA0CBz3Aj8XHa4p2sGMECg2oyB4YIoLAHNICoUBGE-ai-3Q2jNxA7cwLw4dWlHc5CXBawSQvCFbzEr9VF-NdSkMozjLyNcqlqBpZjaTpuj6AZgCGKRqnGSY6AgGY5n+VlQ0UXYqB5M1+WyUhWMnRhIxqfwZ1JAQXnEKQqBkT4lBUPScCwJxaSgUE-CgCL-A0oIrFhBwoCcKAXFKtAV3SsqPGC7wwXCmooAKwInmK7Sypq7AMvqnF6WSdC0mIbzfOoAK+TPEUMMlaVZR1RV3Waxh4F1TB9QTWq0ENTJvV9YB-R+LpaCaHlo1jc10RQRAQAwawOlKnzTomzAk26jMsxzAsEHzIsSy7ctKzFGs63c5pm1bNdAPoogTrOoqkAwRSj1Cm47lfRh50XZcNHwaI0YYPLjBnHqsBnBIHLWDqkEjBMPB0fQzGHUxrDsLhkS4NLeqgAADAASPB2cxQXTBFvBKtUXmGca3LFNZm9wjJvnRbAVRBdvKWfzQ7JpOw4BrDEXiuAGICmjYepqC4L1fJQRHkeYx8J3RlhMagbGl3cfHPEJxgWp5j3Z21mjMJk6xec47ial4w7kAEoTqFAXnZt51Tk6aOQIC4BAzlmHieBt067Zph2lMIi4nxd6L3YXT28c+32oH9rBA5lnKzGbmucZl1S-dqmoEkj-PY6QePTETkBg+vKB-1D-Xw-b5OzYt6QM6znPZiA4A2CoH44HMGnC4RkuUeUivnfY13aAeLu6+sBvK6JzvW+idu+55xToNgxHELYZCVx7k1JutVA5TyAA)). I was able to achieve this (in a somewhat imperfect way) in Flow ([playground link](https://flow.org/try/#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-qBpKJobJYzRwp13WYKG8LRrG8bJggSapumtZZjmUB5gWEBFnUZYVpOvENittQoNFSBskJnakecp7UNcUBDiOY5qPgGjOTQ9CEf245Bf2MS6YsGVIKyXJuGFgII3gxiWDYHCOLY7FBQABrKeAk4FNPGPTeCwsolO46lUCEUTUC7sjuVQNThNgMoNO7qzt5gdEOFQcAlgiDRHDdE+k01RQHD2lZP2Y-9RFonDJ5MGe4PDqOrgw05QN0FA5RBRDo4S9hPG4ZYlMUVR5Q0YtyD0YxlCgJT93vJTIkB7UMhKgghwTNRXAa6tv068u+t9kbdtQ5YJ36-QNv82nuMAt41u2ybA7s-jRf8+UMRuzHXtID7xh+yADucdxj7Pi7BdgAHytTT5YcR1HMIQMALAUO8cCmJjcffQnhFJ5bKeg4OJdm5nlvZ8XkP5+Fm-84R36-r9gEsMB45l4XOdYGnLecUAA)).*

Comment: Could you go the opposite direction?  Avoid the multiple types by changing which one is your source type?

Comment: I'm open to changing the source `Lang<T>` type, as long as it still allows me to express node types and `fold`/`reduce` callbacks (so I think I need to keep generics here). The playground link contains a simplified version of the operations I wanted to define. Any suggestion? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** After going through your playground, it becomes more clear why you want a `Lang<T>` specified in that way. Here's some code on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKaByEAmqC8AUHCXAN5wCulAljgFxwDOMUNAdgOYA0CywjAOQAhDgHkwg3hBRQAhjGiMWbLrwA2ACyaMM2PLyjbdWXKgC+cAD7FSFanWWsOPPiiEBVdhKlwZweUUoJ1VXOShOE30La1sSe1oGZmc1NwE4QQAZGhgAuXVfADd8ynSVF2s4dkoAWwAjAMq6iAh1YDl2Sur1dThLG1JyKkSQl14kdwyANQg6QT6AbkJCAHoVuFBIWDT0NABBAGMYGgh2AB4AFV4PAD44fHJV9cHRbzBGAAoQRgTHZNDpLIFEp-mM4FodHArnAjJCLn0AJT3O4ebhPQZwLwST7fIYOJLlVL+QIgwlhCKMeHmJH4FFotYY7K5eTqHE-YZ-Mm8YrqUqjLhdWoNKBNFptDqCnqI5GY+nPUgzP5fdn4-mcaW0zHo8xLQgTVAAJWAYHUcgOwEuvGEdweFAA2gAFOAcOAAa2AiAgADMoQBdSmO30bEC5dg4Ji7aJwAD8cGEcADDqD5j1-DgezQF2iAFkFAdNHAzgBpXgXG1wMQ1HJnACiIfkRzORpNZotejMpZuvAo+sYRb6XYy+sEN1TKF2h2Op0tmPL9v7LvbeDtgmHvv9cGV6czObzmmLnZpKL6yy9lHYRxOnS9rRwlxuH3YZiiHbgXshGEnV5nZYRlMegwHKcLBvreACM9ybuwL54EeoHqDgj68O+CJLIMUDADAlBQJ0UDnvej6vmQcQYq82JwIUMrviuZGSL6HwUAAdMxhQaMY8E4GBHyFIxEIIoY7E3ghXE8bCSLUmiGKkFi7wUVRTArjJgj0UxLG8OEkQcSJjEaeJ-EkYMTJ5KycmatRWQ5MZyncfpUkkIqSSUWZCmCA51mFLZpDUksKaEGeF5Trh+FloReAwcAyEfvsl7TkuEVQjcf5QgBpAMgAAjATAALQ0JwT4YYw+p+D674bOwTDYcAEZPngcCaHIEYwJoqBAVAGFHGkJEYVhOFvgpNXAIx+r0QNqGEL5-kxbhwBhgEoXpHFSVkilJDddh163mcZIPgN3YGaQtGfBQxLAlAbFMAJEbUjKAAGAAkZAQpYD0nUEz1kLC5g3ZJdkyUdfhAkE6kRBqdz3WQr3QOYD0aV9P1SUZLL-TypSg3AABSaBiJgjFkjQXqINxJTAJ5UkOZ8cGCIUsw4IIJHeeNyyEEB5XwK64WQb8SQAETqAALAArAAbNz4z8EIiP5EUxOMILQt9HAzPAfAJlxZzHI8+oYEAEwAMyi2kEuWSy0u8ukOu6wrSus8wtQc7aGuMNzdTiGAYEG72GS0b4kPBBkADUvgQow6iXYwrontbTCtIN6gQJwHwYbNUAfOoCJIiQDIW1HMe8fHiczXgKcVTU6dwFnetwP7cBy0AA) using a subset of your own example and where `render`, `run` and `fold` seem to type successfully, using the following definitions:

```
type Replace<T, B> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends SSNode ? B : T[P] }
type ASTNodeMatch <K, T> = Omit<Extract<Replace<SSNode, T>, { type: K }>, 'type'>
type SSAction<T, U> = { [K in SSNode['type']]: (x: ASTNodeMatch<K, T>) => U }
```

---

Me and [André Restivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/985686/andr%C3%A9-restivo) have been working in the past 4 hours on this :) We provide two answers, depending on which direction you want to go. However, we think that your `Lang<T>` is ill-formed. What exactly is the `T` supposed to be? Maybe the terminal values? If that is the case, then the `lhs` and `rhs` should point to `Lang<T>` and the `Literal` should be of type `T` and not `string | number | boolean`. Another thing is that your `Lang` properties should all be optional (or else any instance of `Lang` would force it to provide a `Literal`, `UnOp`, `BinOp`, and so on...) We trust you will fix the code appropriately to match your language semantics...

P.S. There is a lot of "intermediate" types that you can get rid of, but we believe this makes it easy to follow the rationale.

---

Going from a *Descriminated Union Type* to a `Lang`:

```
namespace OneWay {
    /* type Lang<T> = {
    Literal?: { value: string | number | boolean },
    BinOp?: { op: string, lhs: T, rhs: T },
    UnOp?: { op: string, arg: T },
    } */

    type ASTNode =
        { type: 'Literal', value: string | number | boolean } |
        { type: 'BinOp', op: string, lhs: ASTNode, rhs: ASTNode } |
        { type: 'UnOp', op: string, arg: ASTNode }

    type Replace<T, A, B> = {
        [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends A ? B : T[P]
    }

    type Lang<T extends ASTNode> = {
        [K in T['type']]?: ASTNodeMatch<K>
    }

    type ASTNodeMatchReplaced<T> = Replace<T, ASTNode, Lang<ASTNode>>
    type ASTNodeMatch<T> = Omit<Extract<ASTNodeMatchReplaced<ASTNode>, { type: T }>, 'type'>

    const node: ASTNode = { type: 'Literal', value: "hello" }
    const node2: Lang<ASTNode> = { Literal: { value: "string" } }
    const node3: Lang<ASTNode> = { BinOp: { op: "+", lhs: node2, rhs: node2 } }
}
```

---

Going from `Lang` to a *Descriminated Union Type*:

```
namespace OrAnother {
    /* type ASTNode =
        { type: 'Literal', value: string | number | boolean } |
        { type: 'BinOp', op: string, lhs: ASTNode, rhs: ASTNode } |
        { type: 'UnOp', op: string, arg: ASTNode }
    */

    type Lang = {
        Literal?: { value: string | number | boolean },
        BinOp?: { op: string, lhs: Lang, rhs: Lang },
        UnOp?: { op: string, arg: Lang },
    } 

    type Replace<T, A> = {
        [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends A ? ASTNode : T[P]
    }

    type Pairs<T> = { [TKey in keyof T]: { type: TKey } & Replace<T[TKey], T> }
    type ASTNode = Pairs<Lang>[keyof Lang]

    const a1: ASTNode = { type: 'Literal', value: "dsda" }
    const a2: ASTNode = { type: 'BinOp', op: "+", lhs: a1, rhs: a1 }

    // These produce Type Errors (as expected)
    const a4: ASTNode = { type: 'BinOp', op: "+", lhs: 3, rhs: a1 } 
    const a5: ASTNode = { type: 'Literal', op: "-" }
}
```